# asp.net radio button grouping

Tags: asp.net, repeater, radio-button

I am currently having an issue with radio buttons and grouping. I have an asp radio button within a repeater control. I have the group name attribute set to "Customer". When the page loads, the radio buttons are not grouped. Instead of the id fields being set to the group name, it is setting the value fields of the radio buttons. I know that I have tried setting radio buttons up outside of a repeater control and have had the same issue. What is going on here?

**aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repCustomers" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="tableDefault" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 383px; border: 0px !important">
            <tr>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>Cust. No.</th>
                <th>Cust. Name</th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="radCustomer" GroupName="Customer" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Customer" ToolTip='<%#Eval("CustomerNumber") %>' />
                </td>
                <td><%#Eval("CustomerNumber")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("Name") %></td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**output html**

```
<table class="tableDefault" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 383px; border: 0px !important">
    <tr>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Cust. No.</th>
        <th>Cust. Name</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="111111"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl01_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl01$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>111111</td>
        <td>Jeremy's Test</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="222222"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl02_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl02$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>222222</td>
        <td>My Test</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="333333"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl03_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl03$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>333333</td>
        <td>Jim Bob's BBQ</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="444444"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl04_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl04$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>444444</td>
        <td>New Hope Hamburgers</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="555555"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl05_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl05$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>555555</td>
        <td>Pied Piper Pizza</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="666666"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl06_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl06$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>666666</td>
        <td>Sandy's Subs</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="777777"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl07_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl07$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>777777</td>
        <td>Leonard's Lambchops</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="888888"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl08_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl08$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>888888</td>
        <td>Dave's Diamond Deli</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <span title="999999"><input id="ctl00_PrimaryContent_repCustomers_ctl09_radCustomer" type="radio" name="ctl00$PrimaryContent$repCustomers$ctl09$Customer" value="radCustomer" /></span>
        </td>
        <td>999999</td>
        <td>Ernie's Eatery</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What version of ASP.Net is this?

Comment: The RadioButtons will be grouped if their 'name', not 'ID', fields are identical.

Comment: Despite your comment about this happening outside of a repeater, I think this particular issue is linked pretty closely with your use of the repeater, as noted by CAbbott. You may want to consider editing your question title to reflect this, if you discover that this is actually the case.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I finally got around this by creating a plain radio button and setting the value using an server-side eval.

```
<input type="radio" name="radCustomer" value='<%#Eval("CustomerNumber") %>' />
```

Now when the application performs a postback, I check for the value of Request.Form["radCustomer"]. This works flawlessly.

Comment: If we need the AutoPostback functionality?

Comment: I couldnt do this because I needed <label for=....>  and cant target the radio without making it a server side control

Comment: Not exactly flawlessly - when the form does not pass some sort of validation then after the postback the radio buttons are not selected - in other words: the choice is not saved between the postbacks.

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, this is a well [known issue with radio buttons within a repeater](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316495/bug-radio-buttons-are-not-mutually-exclusive-when-used-in-a-repeater-server-control).  One of your only options would be to create a custom server control derived from the RadioButton class and override how it renders.

**EDIT**: Here's a sample of what the derived class may look like:

```
public class MyRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<input id=\"" + base.ClientID + "\" ");
        writer.Write("type=\"radio\" ");
        writer.Write("name=\"" + base.ID + "\" ");
        writer.Write("value=\"" + base.ID + "\" />");
        writer.Write("<label for=\"" + base.ClientID + "\">");
        writer.Write(base.Text);
        writer.Write("</label>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow.  This is a pretty big hole in functionality.  Bleh.

Comment: This is based on the idea that you could have a radiobutton group within an item template of the repeater (multiple radio buttons on the same row).  In that case you would want unique grouping based on the mangled id, but most of the time people want what the OP tried to do.

Comment: The `<input />` tag is self closing and should not have an end tag and text inside it.  The text with it should be in a `<label>` tag instead. Final output should be done like the following: `writer.Write("<input id='" + base.ClientID + "' type='radio' name='" + base.ID + "' value='" + base.ID + "' /><label for='" + base.ClientID + "'>" + base.Text + "</label>");`

Comment: Hi, why is the value attribute set to base.ID?

Answer (score 11):

I fixed it in javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $("#divWithGridViewOrRepeater input:radio").attr("name", "yourGroupName");
});
```

Comment: Which this "works" there's a lot of potential for confusion here.  If you're really going with this method be sure you HEAVILY document what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issues. I am using Literal as placeholder to render radio button onItemCreated event.

ASP.Net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rpt_OnItemCreated">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

C#

```
protected void rpt_OnItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    Literal lit = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("lit");
    lit.Text = "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"myGroup\">";
}
```

Comment: Note that you must specify the name attribute (and not solely the id) for the radio-buttons to show up in Request.Form on postback!

Answer (score 2):

I had to modify slightly the answer posted above by r3dsky.

Here's what worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".divWithGridViewOrRepeater input:radio").attr("name", "yourGroupName");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known bug with the ASP.NET Repeater using RadioButtons:
[here best solution in my opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051683/only-one-radiobutton-selection-in-repeater)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding a value on my radiobutton Value='<%#Eval("CustomerNumber") %>'.

Comment: There is not a value attribute for the asp radio button control.

Comment: He probably meant the 'Text' property. ;)

Comment: That's a no go. I knew that it was just going to add a label to it, but I figured that I would try it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I made my radiobutton have autopostback set to true, and then in the event handler set all the other radio buttons to BE unselected.

Not ideal, but I need lots control over the visibility and enabled attributes of the radiobutton, and it seemed easier to let ASP.NET control that rather than resorting to client side script.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
$("input:radio").attr("name", $("input:radio").first().attr("name"));
```

Why? because if you replace the name property for any string you want, you will get an 'not found error'. So, you need to get the name of the first radiobutton, and rename all of them with that name. It works like a sharm ;)

Answer (score 0):

My solution, similar to others:

```
<input id="ctlRadio" runat="server" type="radio" data-fixgroupbug="1" >

// Fixes this ASP.NET bug: if radio input is inside repeater you can't set its name.
// Every input gets set different name by ASP.NET.
// They don't behave as a group. You can select multiple radios.
function fixRadiogroupBug()
{
    $('[type="radio"][data-fixgroupbug]').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    fixRadiogroupBug();
});
```