# only one radiobutton selection in repeater

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, repeater

I want to select only one radio button but I cant do this.
Here is my code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater_secenekler" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Eval("Secenekler")%>'>
   <HeaderTemplate>
       <table>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
           <td style="margin-left: 20px;">
               <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' Visible='<%# Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "1" %>' />
               <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OptionName")%>' Visible='<%# Eval("TypeId").ToString() == "2" %>'
                    GroupName="RadioButtonGrup" />
           </td>
       </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <FooterTemplate>
       </table>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I can select all radio button with same groupname but I dont want this. I want only one selection.

How can I do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a well known bug with the ASP.NET Repeater using RadioButtons:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q316495

There is a fix available here:

http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/87/Simple-fix-for-Radio-Button-controls-in-an-ASP-NET-Repeater-using-jQuery

```
jQuery("[name$='$optValue']").attr("name",jQuery("[name$='$optValue']").attr("name"));

jQuery("[name$='$optValue]").click(function (){ 
                //set name for all to name of clicked 
                jQuery("[name$='$optValue]").attr("name", this.attr("name")); 
            });
```

Comment: great shout... have a donut ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Just a quick fix of the above answer so you don't get any errors when the script is executed.

```
    $(function () {
    $('[name$="$YourGroupName"]').attr("name", $('[name$="$YourGroupName"]').attr("name"));

    $('[name$="$YourGroupName"]').click(function () {
        //set name for all to name of clicked 
        $('[name$="$YourGroupName"]').attr("name", $(this).attr("name"));
    });
});
```

Comment: In fact the previous solution didn't work for me until you (@xfan) made this fix. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you! This answer cleared my issues with the fix right up.

Comment: Why not just set the name attribute of all the radio buttons to the same value and leave it at that?