# How to select just a radiobutton in a repeater with postback

Tags: c#, jquery, radio-button, selection, repeater

As I found on Internet that there is a bug from MS when we add a RadioButton inside repeater for selecting just one.

But I found this code here that solved my problem. ([only one radiobutton selection in repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051683/only-one-radiobutton-selection-in-repeater))

```
$(function () {
    $('[name$="$YourGroupName"]').attr("name", $('[name$="$YourGroupName"]').attr("name"));

    $('[name$="$YourGroupName"]').click(function () {
        //set name for all to name of clicked 
        $('[name$="$YourGroupName"]').attr("name", $(this).attr("name"));
    });
});
```

But it only works when the radiobutton is not set to autopostback. But I need to do a postback when I select a radiobutton and a response to the database. But.... anytime that I do a click on a radiobutton with postback, always the first in the list is selected and the ItemDataBound it's not working because of the jquery function which it's renaming all the radiobuttons with the same name.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this script instead of the one you're using at the end of the page after the repeater :

`<script>
    var radios = $("input:radio");
    radios.click(function () {
        radios.removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
        //$(this).attr('checked', 'checked'); // jQuery < 1.6
        return true;
    });
</script>`

This will allow the AutoPostBack of your radiobutton to work again.