# How can I group radio buttons in a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

I am using a nester repeater to dynamically build a list of radio buttons in a table:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAccID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </td>
                     <td>  
                            <%-- POPULATE CONDITION RADIO BUTTONS --%>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rpConditionRadioButtons" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbCondition" GroupName="gCondition" Text="" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                     </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

But I can't figure out how to group them together. (Because the table is built on the fly I don't think I can use a radio button list.)

I have tried using the GroupName attribute, and setting the ClientIDMode to Static, but this didn't help.

Comment: I'm getting the opposite problem - rather than all the radio buttons being in group across all the rows in the repeater, they are operating independently.

Answer (score 0):

If you nest a repeater you have also a parent `RepeaterItem` with an unique identifier(e.g. a primary key). You can append that to the `GroupName` property dynamically in `ItemDataBound` of the inner repeater. You can access the outer repeater's current `RepeaterItem` from the inner repeater's `ItemDataBound` in the following way (assuming that `lblAccID.Text` contains the ID) :

```
protected void rpConditionRadioButtons_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater innerRepeater = (Repeater)sender;
        RepeaterItem outerItem = (RepeaterItem)innerRepeater.NamingContainer;
        Label lblAccID = (Label)outerItem.FindControl("lblAccID");
        RadioButton rbCondition = (RadioButton) e.Item.FindControl("rbCondition");
        rbCondition.GroupName = "gCondition_" + lblAccID.Text;
    }
}
```

Comments:

> OK - Found the radio buttons, and can change their attributes, but
>   they still work independently.

I'm afraid this is a [**known bug**](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q316495).

Have a look at this question for further assistance: [asp.net radio button grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334926/asp-net-radio-button-grouping)

Comment: @Ben: But `rpConditionRadioButtons_ItemDataBound` is triggered correctly for your inner repeater, have you used the debugger?

Comment: OK - Found the radio buttons, and can change their attributes, but they still work independently.

Comment: @Ben: I'm afraid this is a known bug: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q316495 Have a look at this question for further assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334926/asp-net-radio-button-grouping