# Radio button inside repeater + grouping + without JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

I have a repeater inside which I have asp.net radio button control. I want to group these radio button so that at a time only radio is selected.

I know that this can be easily achieved by writing a JavaScript function but I want to make this work even if JavaScript of browser is disabled so I need to write something at server side. How can I do that?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334926/asp-net-radio-button-grouping

Comment: But if you add  **GroupName** same to all then it will work

Comment: I have included GroupName but still it's not working, just for your clear understanding, I am having radio button not radio button list

Comment: pratik, did you ever find a suitable work-around?