# Custom Radio Buttons inside Repeater events

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create a custom radio button 
My code is like :

```
 public class MyRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("<input id=\"" + base.ClientID + "\" ");
        writer.Write("type=\"radio\" ");
        writer.Write("name=\"" + base.ID + "\" ");
        writer.Write("value=\"" + base.ID + "\" />");
        writer.Write("<label for=\"" + base.ClientID + "\">");
        writer.Write(base.Text);
        writer.Write("</label>");
    }
}
```

I inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334926/asp-net-radio-button-grouping):  Everything works fine, but when I want to know what button was checked is not working fine. I don't want to to have on custom radio button `AUTOPOSTBACK=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Request.Form[base.ID] inside your radio button control for getting checked radio button value.