# Access all RadioButton from a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `Repeater` of `RadioButton`.  Is there an easy way to access all these `RadioButton` from the C# side?  For example, maybe access by the `GroupName`?  I couldn't find anything simple online.

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptOtherNetworks" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <li data-theme="c" data-role="list-divider" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-b">
            <asp:Localize ID="locRecentlySelected" runat="server"
                EnableViewState="False" meta:resourcekey="locRecentlySelectedResource1"
                Text="Select Network from Other Cameras">
            </asp:Localize>
        </li>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li data-theme="c">
            <!-- I want to access these -->
            <asp:RadioButton Text='<%# Eval("NetworkDescription") %>' data-mac='<%# Eval("MAC") %>'
                Checked="False" GroupName="RadioGroupNetworkCameras" runat="server" />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: on which method u want to access radio buttons...like on rowbound event,page_load event,etc

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar It's an `OnClick` event of a button on the same ASPX file.

Comment: that button is out side Repeater ??

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar Yes.

Comment: then you can refer answer given by j.f. you can iterate through all RadioButton using for each loop for repeater items

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can retrieve all of the RadioButtons by finding them by their ID in each of the RepeaterItems.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb"
    Text='<%# Eval("NetworkDescription") %>'
    data-mac='<%# Eval("MAC") %>'
    Checked="False"
    GroupName="RadioGroupNetworkCameras"
    runat="server" />
```

```cs
foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rptOtherNetworks.Items)
{
    if (ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || ri.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        RadioButton r = (RadioButton)ri.FindControl("rb");
    }
}
```

But a problem you are going to run into is that within the Repeater, the radio buttons [will not be mutually exclusive](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q316495). There are various ways of ["fixing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334926/asp-net-radio-button-grouping) this through JavaScript and other methods, but just be aware this.