# ASP:Repeater and embedded radiobuttons

Tags: asp.net, webforms, radio-button, repeater

I'm using a Repeater control to display a series of photos on an ASP.NET web form. Here is my current code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repPhotos" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:hyperlink id="link" NavigateUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' runat="server">
      <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' Height="10%" Width="10%" />
    </asp:hyperlink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now I would like to include a radiobutton displayed beneath each photo, but the series of radiobuttons must be mutually exclusive. I tried using the ASP:RadioButton control, but was having difficulty preventing multiple radiobuttons from being simultaneously selected and I'm not sure how the ASP:RadioButtonList could work with the Repeater.

Your suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net radio button grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334926/asp-net-radio-button-grouping). Turned out to be a bug. The linked thread mentions the bug report and gives workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, RadioButton's **GroupName** doesn't work inside Repeater or GridView *if they are placed inside individual row*. However, you can easily achieve it using a couple of line of **jQuery**.

```
function radioButtonClick(sender) {
    $('.myRadioButton input').attr("checked", false);
    $(sender).prop("checked", true);
}
```

When a radio button is clicked, uncheck all radio buttons with ***myRadioButton*** class name. Then check only one triggered the click event.

### ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebForm.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater ID="repPhotos" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="PhotoRadioButton"
                    CssClass="myRadioButton" onclick="radioButtonClick(this)" />
                <%# Container.DataItem %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function radioButtonClick(sender) {
                $('.myRadioButton input').attr("checked", false);
                $(sender).prop("checked", true);
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DemoWebForm
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            repPhotos.DataSource = new List<string> {"One", "Two", "Three"};
            repPhotos.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick! But the radiobuttons appear to the left of each image. I was hoping to make them appear underneath the images, but haven't managed to figure that one out yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want to use CSS or html tag to style it. Easiest way is to place it inside `<p>` tag. For example, `<ItemTemplate><p><asp:RadioButton ..></p></ItemTemplate>`

Comment: The problem with this is that after wrapping the radiobutton in the <p> tag, now the photos display vertically down the page instead of horizontally across the page.

Comment: Could you create a new question, and include mark-up and a screenshot?

Comment: Just added it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034891/asprepeater-and-embedded-radiobuttons-cont